# WPF ListBox Custom Style

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have a ListBox with a custom layout for the items set within a Grid. I have set a style as a static resource in the grid to define the foreground color of the textblock but it does not bind to my view model. It works fine if I specify the value as a standard color. Also all data is binding correctly, what am I missing?

```
           <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <Grid HorizontalAlignment="Stretch" >
                        <Grid.Resources>
                            <Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="HeaderForeground">
                                <Setter Property="Foreground"  Value="{Binding Path=ScreenConfig.TimeColor,Mode=OneWay, NotifyOnTargetUpdated=True}" />
                            </Style>
                        </Grid.Resources>

                        <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=Time}" Style="{StaticResource HeaderForeground}" />
```

Comment: What type is TimeColor? Where are the ScreenConfig property defined? What's the ItemsSource of your ListBox?

Comment: The ItemSource is an observable object in the viewmodel and ScreenConfig is a class in the viewmodel. If I bind to the ScreenConfig for controls not within the listbox template it works fine.

Comment: Please post the defintion of your classes...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If `ScreenConfig` is a property of your view model, you could use a `RelativeSource` to bind to it:

```
<Style TargetType="TextBlock" x:Key="HeaderForeground">
    <Setter Property="Foreground" 
            Value="{Binding Path=DataContext.ScreenConfig.TimeColor, RelativeSource={RelativeSource AncestorType=ListBox}}" />
</Style>
```

The `DataContext` of an item in a `ListBox` is the current item in the `ListBox`'s `ItemsSource` and that's why your binding doesn't work.

Comment: Sorry, it should be `AncestorType` and not `AncestorLevel`. I edited my answer.